# Best epoxy to seal indoor plywood subfloor?

Tags: flooring, sealing, plywood, sealant, epoxy

I want to put a coat of sealant such as epoxy over the plywood subfloors in my house since I’m already ripping out the carpets and replacing with hardwood (actually engineered floating cork flooring).

I live right by the ocean so I figure might as well get as much moisture protection as possible. Sometimes we also rent out to Airbnb guests who may leave the window open when it rains.

I see epoxy on many articles as the recommended option and West System as a recommended brand. However, I live close to a Home Depot and they don’t have West System epoxy, but they do have an overwhelming number of other epoxy options, especially by J-B Weld.

What are the best exact products people have used for sealing plywood flooring indoors? And I assume I’d use a foam roller to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Home Depot Has It" is not a great reason to choose an epoxy, since they are not a particularly good epoxy supplier.

Online suppliers and West Marine Stores (not, as far as I can tell, actually otherwise associated with West System) or **any** boat store will have it. Boat folks know epoxy, depend on it, and carry the good stuff.

You live right by the ocean? You can find West System Epoxy. You're just looking the wrong place for it.

Personally, I'd use 105/207 for most things, but 105/206 would be fine (and cost less) for sealing floors, so long as you use all the 206 you buy in 6 months or so. 105 will last more-or-less forever. So will 207. 205/206 go bad, or at least pink.

For the actual use, I'd probably just slap some polyurethane on the subfloor and have a lot more money left over, but if you want epoxy, of a reasonable standard for marine use, West Systems is a good choice, which is why the articles you've read recommend it.

Comment: Does the "wet system" absorb into the plywood or something?  My default instinct for epoxy on wood subfloors is that the subfloors change dimensions seasonally and any epoxy stuck in the joins could cause your floor to buckle or at a bare minimum the epoxy would delaminate from the wood and turn into little pieces to make your floor sound like a musical instrument when walked on.

Comment: Thank you! Sounds like I’ll just go with a bucket of oil-based polyurethane then. Oil-based because it’s cheaper, and I don’t care about the color, and I have the time for it to dry.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger it is West System (a brand name) and it is fairly low viscosity so it does, in fact soak in to a large extent, unless you are going to pour so much that you're trying to level your floors with it (expensive, and you'll find a lot of little holes dribbling epoxy...because it's low viscosity and houses are rarely level or perfectly sealed.) You could \certainly roll on a seal coat and expect it to stay put.  But I do think polyurethane is a more reasonable approach to the concern of water resistance, here, unless you are fiberglassing over the floor, not just sealing it.

Comment: Hmmm... fiberglass-reinforced sub-floors. You may be on to something... :D